# SocketTimeoutException when container in Pod try to contact Kubernetes API Server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a Kubernetes cluster deployed locally with Kubeadm/Vagrant with a master and two workers with the following IPs:
master: 192.168.250.10
worker1: 192.168.250.11
worker2: 192.168.250.12

then I have an application composed by a ReactJS frontend and SpringBoot backend running in two separate containers on the same Pod. When I submit a form on the frontend the application calls an API in the backend that internally calls a Kubernetes API. To authenticate to the cluster I use a .kube/config file correctly configured.

When the application (frontend/backend) is outside the cluster everything works fine. I use docker-compose to startup the two containers just for the unit tests. The .kube/config file has as API URL https://192.168.250.10:6443. The problem is when I try to run the application in the containers the IP 192.168.250.10 doesn't work properly and communication goes in Timeout exception.

I am sure the application is OK because the same application works fine in IBM Cloud wherein .kube/config there is an API server with public IP reachable.

My question is, which IP should I put into .kube/config when I run the application locally inside my cluster? How can I get this IP using kubectl commands?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which connection times out? There are no details to start with.

Comment: My backend running in the Pod fails when try to connect to API Server URL using the master IP 192.168.205.10:6443. I think I should use another IP but I do not know which to use. Consider the Java code that tries the connection to that URL run inside the container in the Pod.

Comment: well, if you say that's the IP, then that's the IP. im guessing you don't have node to node communication configured. So your app, running on the worker node can't get to the master node. Just create a pod, get into it, and see if you can reach api-server manually.

Comment: Inside kubernetes use `kubernetes.default` dns name to resolve ip address of api-server

Comment: Logged on my pod and tried ping kubernetes.default, the IP is resolved in 10.96.0.1 but no ping occurs.

Comment: Ping doesn't work with service's cluster IPs, as it is a virtual IP. You should be able to ping a specific pod, but not a service.

Comment: @suren I have a node to node communication. I tried to log in on my pod and I can contact the Kubernetes API server using two IP I got logging on Kubernetes API Pod, but when I replace it in my config and redeploy it doesn't work. I have an issue with curl and I cannot test the API server inside my Pod.

Comment: can you say what is exactly that you are curling manually and from your app? From what you are saying, the endpoints you can reach are `https://192.168.205.10:6443` (this one is because the host network is set to true), 10.96.0.1, on port 443 I assume (or `https://kubernetes:443/`), and whatever is the endpoint of this service (which is the real api-server pod). you should be able to reach any of them from your app, if your cluster is working properly. It doesn't mean that you are going to get ok (unless you authenticate yourself), but you should get a response. A forbidden. Can you?